# How to force re-read of properties file in JSP page on the browser

Tags: java, html, jsp

It looks like the browser is caching the values read from a properties file. I do not want to email all the users of the webpage to ask them to clear the cache because there's a change in a property. Surely there must be a way to force a re-read? I don't mind a proper read every time the page is opened, but on the console I can see the Tomcat server did actually read the correct (new) values, so it must be browser caching.
This is my code, standard java, in a file called MyUtils.java:

```
/**
 * @return Properties from properties file set in folder: /tomcat/conf/TSprops.properties
 */
public Properties getProperties() {
    String serverRoot = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
    String propsFile=serverRoot+"/conf/TSprops.properties"; 
    try {
        FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream( propsFile );
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load( inp );
        inp.close();
        return props;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

in my .JSP file I have:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <jsp:useBean id="ut" scope="page" class="MyUtils" />
    <html>
    <%
        Properties props = ut.getProperties();
        String NBH=props.getProperty("NextBankHol", "");
    %>
    <body>
    Next Bank Holiday: <%=NBH%>
```

When I display the value of NBH, it shows the 'old' value rather than the one I just changed it to.
I only see the correct value when I clear the browser's cache.

Comment: The properties are a server side construct and have nothing to do with client side. It is more likely that the whole generated page is cached. You can verify this with the browser's developer tools. With the dev tools you can also check wether the HTTP cache headers are set appropriately. As a rule of thumb generated HTML pages shouldn't be allowed to be cached. See https://www.keycdn.com/blog/http-cache-headers

Comment: You're absolutely right. I had part on the client side and that actually worked, another part was accessed through a servlet and that got cached. Annoyingly I have not been able to solve the caching issue with the servlet, but solved the problem by moving the important code from the servlet to the JSP and that now works. Thanks for the comment, that made me look again.